# My fantasy baseball loop is not behaving as anticipated

Tags: python, for-loop

I am having some trouble with a for loop using multiple lists. I am reading in a file as a data frame with a certain name and then performing a few operations on that data frame before saving it and going onto the next data frame. Below is my code:

```
for (i, j, k) in zip(pos, file, num):
    i = pd.read_csv(j)
    i["Points"] = -i.AB*1+i.H*5.6+i["2B"]*2.9+i["3B"]*5.7+i.HR*9.4+i.BB*3+i.HBP*3+i.SB*1.9-i.CS*2.8
    i = i.sort_values(by = ["Points"], ascending = False)
    i = i.head(k)
```

When I run this I don't get an error but when I try to print a value from pos I get an error saying the name is not defined. But if I print i it returns the data frame I would expect in the last iteration. Am I searched and found some helpful stuff but still can't solve my problem. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but you set ```i``` equal to an element from ```pos```, then set ```i=pd.read_csv(j)```. Also will you format your code to show what is/isn't in the for loop?

Comment: Can you edit the complete error message into your question?